# Reading values from a file and splitting them into two lists with stream in Java

Tags: java, file, arraylist, split, java-stream

Let's say we have a file with a give input like this

```
List1,List2,List3,List4,List5,List6,List7.......
.....List8,List9
ListX1,ListX2,ListX3.......
```

After List9 entery, there is a new line character. How would I be able to tell the stream to collect elements before a new line character into a single list, and collect the rest into the second list?

```
List<String> fWire = new ArrayList<String>();
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(filePath))) {
        .......
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Are you saying that each input line should be parsed into a separate List?

Comment: There are only two lines, so technically, yes, each input line should be parse into a separated list.

Comment: To me using stream for such task if overdoing it. Simply do it the standard way.

Comment: If there is a pattern that the two lists follow you can use the filter function and accordingly dump it into respective lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need a `List<List<String>>`. Each inner `List` will represent one line of input:

```
List<List<String>> lists = null;
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(filePath))) {
    lists = stream.map(s -> Arrays.asList(s.split(",")))
                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```